# Find available openings using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, schedule

I have a table of appointments with records having two fields - start_date and end_date, both datetime. There is no overlap of time periods in the table.

Given a specific period (search_start and search_end), I need to generate a list of all openings between those appointments (from and to) using SQL.

For example: given two appointments in the table:

September 15, 2016 08:00 to September 15, 2016 09:00

September 15, 2016 10:00 to September 15, 2016 12:00

And given search parameters start= September 1, 2016 00:00 and end= September 30, 2016 23:59, the results should be

September 1, 2016 00:00 to September 15, 2016 08:00

September 15, 2016 09:00 to September 15, 2016 10:00

September 15, 2016 12:00 to September 30, 2016 23:59

Here is a script to generate a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](   
[from_date] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
[to_date] [datetime] NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ( [from_date] ASC ) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] ([from_date], [to_date]) VALUES (CAST(0x0000A6820083D600 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A682009450C0 AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[Table_1] ([from_date], [to_date]) VALUES (CAST(0x0000A68200A4CB80 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68200C5C100 AS DateTime))
```

I am using MSSQL 2008 R2

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Given what you posted there is no chance we can help.

Comment: Which version of SQL?

Comment: You just want to display all the result between two dates?

Comment: Please update your question with the table structure and SQL that you already tried. From the question it is not clear where you got stuck, or if you even know SQL and started developing.

Comment: This same basic issue comes up regularly. See Itzik Ben-Gan's [Gaps and Islands](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions) for the highest performance solution to this kind of problem. Using JOIN or APPLY to fold the dataset back on itself will scale very poorly whereas the window function approach in the article remains performant even with large datasets.

Comment: I need to display all of the gaps between the existing appointment records starting with a given start date and ending with a given end date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your values I got the output you wanted : )

```
DECLARE @start datetime = '2016-09-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @finish datetime = '2016-09-30 23:59:00'

WITH rn AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start) AS rn FROM opening)
SELECT CASE WHEN r1.rn = 1 THEN @start
                           ELSE r2.finish
       END as START,
       CASE WHEN r1.rn IS NULL THEN @finish
                               ELSE r1.start
       END  AS FINISH
    FROM rn r1 
        FULL OUTER JOIN rn r2 
            ON r1.rn = r2.rn + 1
    WHERE ISNULL(r1.start, 0) != @start
```

`opening` is your schedule/appointment table.  `start` is the starting date in your table and `finish` is the end date in your table.  `@start` is the starting date and `@finish` is the end date.  You obvious don't need to use `@start, @finish`.  I just put it there for testing.

Comment: This works great ! I am just wondering if there is a more cost effective way to do it from a performance perspective. See for example examples 3 and 4 at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/25/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement-part-4/  compared to example 2, but i couldnt get 3 and 4 to work with my case.

Comment: @user1480192 I am sure there is a way.  Did you make sure to check everyone else's queries?  There is often multiple ways to do a single task so someone else might have found a possibly more efficient way.  Mine is pretty straight forward.  I'll look into it to see if I can make it better.

Comment: @user1480192 Do you know how long it took you to process the information with my query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Start_Date, End_Date
FROM TableName
BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date
```

This question seems easy?? I am not sure, if I have oversimplified your question?

You just have to make sure, you add the time bit as well!

Comment: This wouldn't work.  He essentially wants the times inbetween the two user inputed datetime values (`start and end`) that does not exist in the his table.  Think of it in terms of `int`.  In his table he has `start 4, end 6` and `start 9, end 10`.  If his user inputed `start, end` is `0, 10` then he wants `0, 4 - 6, 9`.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking like Mfredy on this question.  But I will give my standard spiel on what to look out for on data time calculations.

Here are some common issues.
Some (like Mysql) sql engines store the data in GMT (some time zone in england).  Then they calculate the number of hours off of GMT to get the actual time.  So if you are 8 hours from GMT you may be 8 hours off if you used a MsSql client connecting to a MySql database.  Because MsSql does not understand this 8 hour delta for GMT used by MySql.  You can also see this in applications and operating systems.

The other issue is you are thinking in dates you have to make sure you are thinking in Date and Time unless you converted the date time to a date.

Watch out for < vs <=.  If you are filtering for the end date.  Say for example Last day in january is to be included but first day of feb is not.  It is better to do < 02/01 that it is to do <= 1/31.  You may chop off records if you compare using <= and don't go down to the last millisecond before 02/01.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go trying to re-create your scenario, and then solve it. In some places I've simplified things for the sake of the example, but you should be able to extrapolate it.

I'm sure there are also far more elegant ways, but is a starting point, and I quite enjoyed figuring it out.

The approach I wanted to take was build a list of the available 'time slots'

First, I created a table with the available Hours for bookings

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HOURS](
HourID [int] NULL) 

INSERT INTO dbo.[hours] VALUES (9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17)
```

Then did the same for the minute intervals (I went with 5 min intervals for simplicity)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].MINS(
MinID [int] NULL    ) 

INSERT INTO dbo.mins VALUES (5),(10),(15),(20),(25),(30),(35),(40),(45),(50),(55),(60)
```

and same again for dates I wanted to work with

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].DATES(
DATES [Date] NULL) 

INSERT INTO dbo.DATES values
('20160901'),('20160902')
```

Using these tables, I created a view listing all available 'slots'

```
CREATE VIEW AllTimeSlots AS
SELECT 
cast(dates AS datetime) + cast(DATEADD(hour, hourid, DATEADD(minute, minid, DATEADD(second, 00, 0))) AS datetime) AS TimeSlot
FROM dbo.[hours] CROSS JOIN dbo.mins CROSS JOIN dates
```

I then created a table containing the appointments

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Appointments(
AppointmentStart [Datetime] NULL,
AppointmentEnd [DateTime] null
) 

INSERT INTO dbo.Appointments
VALUES
('20160901 10:40:00 AM','20160901 10:55 AM'),('20160901 01:00:00 PM','20160901 02:05:00 PM')
```

Then, I created another view with married up the slots and the bookings. Take note of the joins I'm using to block out all slots between the two times

```
CREATE VIEW SlotAvailability 
AS
SELECT TimeSlot,CASE WHEN AppointmentStart IS NULL THEN 'Free' ELSE 'Booked' END AS [Availability]
FROM (
SELECT Timeslot,apt.AppointmentStart, apt.AppointmentEnd FROM
 dbo.AllTimeSlots ats
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.Appointments apt
 on ats.TimeSlot >= appointmentstart and ats.timeslot <= appointmentend) q1
```

Doing

```
Select Timeslot, [availability] from SlotAvailability where [availability] = 'free'
```

will list all the available time slots.

The last bit, which I haven't quite got to (and ran out of time for now) is then converting this to a start-end time for each 'free' slot - tried a couple of methods, but didn't crack it - I think if you join that table (view) to itself of timeslot+5mins, you should be able to then min/max values based on whether it's the start / end of a free block

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally address this today is to use the APPLY operator to join the table to itself. There's not enough info in the question to craft a complete query for you, but here's the general pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t1
OUTER APPLY ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM MyTable t 
    WHERE t.KeyFields = t1.KeyFields
        AND t.SequenceField > t1.SequenceField
 ) t2
```

Now I can compare each row directly with the one the follows in my WHERE clause, such that the WHERE clause the filter it down to only show rows where there is a gap.

You can also sometimes accomplish this via the [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) or [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) Windowing Functions.

Comment: Curious.  What kind of information are you missing?